# Validate multiple endpoints using HTML status codes before failing when consuming a asmx web service C#

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, httprequest, endpoint

I am currently using a web service, which offers 2 endpoints, as backups for fall over. I need to test all 2 endpoints  before my code completely fails and then will need to log the exception. My thoughts were to be to return the status code of the HTML response using this:

**Function1:**

```
public string   ValidateHttpRequest(string endpointUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            var url = endpointUrl;
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var reponse = httpClient.GetAsync(endpointUrl);
            return reponse.Result.StatusCode.ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Log("exception thrown in ValidateHttpRequest()!  " + ex.ToString());
            Log.Log(ex);
            return null;

        }
    }
```

This is called from another function, say function2().

**Function 2:**

```
 private bool function2()
        {

            //Specify the binding to be used for the client.
            BasicHttpsBinding binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();

            var epA = "https://www1.endpoint1.com/endpointService.asmx";
            var epB = "https://www2.endpoint1.com/endpointService.asmx";


            if (ValidateHttpRequest(epA)== "OK")
            {
                EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("https://www1.enpoint1.com/endpointService.asmx");
                _Client = new WebService.SoapClient(binding, address);
                return true;
            }
            else if ((ValidateHttpRequest(epB))== "OK")
            { 

               EndpointAddress address2 = new EndpointAddress(("https://www2.enpoint2.com/endpointService.asmx")); 
         else
            {
                 // Now Log error here completely, and only fail here if both above checks return anything apart from 200 status code     

                LogException(“Only log exception if all endpoints fail”);
                return false;
            }

        }
```

This is all well and good, however I need this to not fail on the first call, as I will need to check if the other endpoint is valid/active. The issue is that if the response is null, the exception is handled and I will not check the rest of my endpoints, how can I correctly ensure my code is safe with i.e. exceptions are handled correctly, but continuing my code to check all endpoints before completely failing and halting execution. it should fail if i receive  any other response apart from 200 OK I have researched about how to check the HTTP response and all that I can come up with is this but it doesn’t completely suit my needs .If anyone could point me in the right direction or help with a solution I would be very grateful. 
Thanks in advance